# JavaScript always returns true

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom-events

I add this script in jsp file.

This function always returns true even for failed scenarios like without matching the expression and everything.

Why it happens like that? How to solve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("mail").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML="";

    var expression = /^[a-zA-Z_.0-9]+$/;
    var mailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}+$/;
    var numberExp = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if(!document.getElementById('username').value.match(expression))
    {
        document.getElementById('username').focus();
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML=" Enter valid user name";
        return false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('password').value.length == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('password').focus();
        document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = "Fill Password field";
        document.getElementById("pass").style.visibility = "visible";
        return false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('cnfpassword').value.length == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('cnfpassword').focus();
        document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = "Fill confirm Password field";
        document.getElementById("pass").style.visibility = "visible";
        return false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('password').value != document.getElementById('cnfpassword').value)
    {
        document.getElementById('password').focus();
        document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = "Password and confirm password Not match";
        document.getElementById("pass").style.visibility = "visible";
        return false;
    }
    if(!document.getElementById('emailid').value.match(expression))
    {
        document.getElementById('emailid').focus();
        document.getElementById("mail").innerHTML=" Enter valid E-mailID";
        document.getElementById("mail").style.visibility = "visible";
        return false;
    }
    if(!document.getElementById('number').value.match(numberExp))
    {
        document.getElementById('number').focus();
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML=" Enter only numbers";
        document.getElementById("number").style.visibility = "visible";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: you codes need to be re-factored!!

Comment: Hi @karthik could you show an example of your html as well please?

Comment: Could you put it on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: s i copied it in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the refactoring advices, the easiest thing would be to use Firebug and debug what is doing wrong. It will save you a lot of headaches

Comment: +1 because using firebug or similar should identify exactly where the problem is, and should help you fix it. Trying to identify problems in a large piece of js like this is not easy.

Answer (score 3):

change 
`document.getElementById('password').value.length == 0`

to

`document.getElementById('password').value.length === 0`

**In javascript**

**Below All will return true**

```
0==""      
0== "0"
false== "0"
null== undefined
0==' \t\r\n '
```

Solution

**Below All will return false**

```
0===""      
0=== "0"
false=== "0"
null=== undefined
0===' \t\r\n '
```

the **"=="** and **"!="** operator will try to **coerce** the two values into the same type before the comparison is made.

the **"==="** and **"!=="** operator (also know as **identity operators**) check the type and values at the time of comparison

Comment: @Karthik == != === in Javascript

Answer (score 1):

What the above have said are correct, the else was only corresponding to the last `if`.

Also note that == is not the same as ===.

Also, might be better to have only one `return` statement in your function.